# Automatically integrate feature image to wordpress article via API

Tags: images, uploads

I have created a scenario with the automation Platform Make **to automate my Wordpress article redaction.**

I start from entering inputs in a Tally form, then Make send it to OpenAI API to redact the content, and all the data are send through the Wordpress API to write an article.

In my Tally form I have a field which take an image as an input and **I would like this image to be used as the featured image of the Wordpress article.**

Here is what my Make scenario looks like :
[image]

In the "Create a Post" module the only add it take for the featured image of the post is an ID, so the image already need to be uploaded to my Wordpress media library :

[image]

So after my post is created with this module (without featured image), I add the image to the media library with the "Create a Media Item" module :

[image]

We can't see it on the screenshot but there is a "Post ID" field in this module so I can link the image to my post without problem. The problem lies in what I should put in the "data" field so that it upload an actual image and not this array.

Here is the "Image[]" object as retrieved from Tally :

[image]

I tried to directly put the array in the "data" field and I also tried to put every other subfield but none of them give me the proper image.

Any help on that matter will be deeply appreciated, thanks.